# Get all <td> values of <tr> to give row totals in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a series of `<tr>`s in a `table` I am trying to get row totals for by getting and adding all the `td` values. I am working in the console log and I get an array of td cells like:

```
[<td class="_3">4</td>, <td class="_3">8</td>, ...]
```

The table html is

```
 <tr class="_3 table-side-row">
    <td class="_3">4</td>
    <td class="_3">8</td>
    ...
 </tr>
```

My Jquery

```
$('#table1 .table-side-row ._3').each(function () {
    // initialize row count
    var sum = 0;
    //find the td value in current row and sum it
    $(this).find('td').each(function () {
        var cell = $(this).html(); // also tried val() here
            sum += parseInt(cell);

    });
    // alert row total
    alert(sum);
});
```

This alerts `0` a lot of times. If I call alert inside the second loop it never is raised. So my 2nd loop must be wrong, but I'm unsure why?

Comment: You can't find td, cause you are already there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector should be `#table1 .table-side-row._3`:

```js
$('#table1 .table-side-row._3').each(function() {
  // initialize row count
  var sum = 0;
  //find the td value in current row and sum it
  $(this).find('td').each(function() {
    var cell = $(this).html(); // also tried val() here
    sum += parseInt(cell);

  });
  // alert row total
  alert(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <tr class="_3 table-side-row">
    <td class="_3">4</td>
    <td class="_3">8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Current problem is that the selector `$('#table1 .table-side-row ._3')` refers to `td` elements not `tr`. As a result `$(this).find('td')` will return empty object thus you are getting `0`

Change your selector to

```
$('#table1 .table-side-row._3'); //or $('#table1 .table-side-row')
```

instead of

```
$('#table1 .table-side-row ._3')
```

Also, Always use `radix` with [`parseInt(strNum, radix)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with the first selector:

```
#table1 .table-side-row ._3
```

This will select all your cells, instead of your rows.

I would remove the `._3`, as it is not necessary, and also confusing, because the same class applies to the rows and the cells.